# Creating Python zip for AWS Lambda using Bazel

Tags: python, aws-lambda, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-python

I've a monorepo that contains a set of Python AWS lambdas and I'm using [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) for building and packaging the lambdas. I'm now trying to use Bazel to create a zip file that follows the expected [AWS Lambdas packaging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) and that I can upload to Lambda. Wondering what's the best way to do this with Bazel?

Below are a few different things I've tried thus far:

***Attempt 1: py_binary***

BUILD.bazel

```
py_binary(
name = "main_binary",
srcs = glob(["*.py"]),
main = "main.py",
visibility = ["//appcode/api/transaction_details:__subpackages__"],
deps = [
        requirement("Faker"),
    ],
)
```

**Problem:**

This generates the following:

- main_binary (python executable)
- main_binary.runfiles
- main_binary.runfiles_manifest

Lambda expects the handler to be in the format of `lambda_function.lambda_handler`. Since `main_binary` is an executable vs. a python file, it doesn't expose the actual handler method and the lambda blows up because it can't find it. I tried updating the handler configuration to simply point to the `main_binary` but it blows up because it expects two arguments(i.e. `lambda_function.lambda_handler`).

***Attempt 2: py_library + pkg_zip***

BUILD.bazel

```
py_library(
name = "main",
srcs = glob(["*.py"]),
visibility = ["//appcode/api/transaction_details:__subpackages__"],
deps = [
        requirement("Faker"),
    ],
)

pkg_zip(
name = "main_zip",
srcs =["//appcode/api/transaction_details/src:main" ],
)
```

**Problem:**

This generates a zip file with:

- main.py
- `__init__.py`

The zip file now includes the `main.py` but none of its runtime dependencies. Thus the lambda blows up because it can't find `Faker`.

***Other Attempts:***

I've also tried using the `--build_python_zip` flag as well as the `@bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper` with a generic rule but they both lead to similar outcomes as the two previous attempts.

Comment: I have no straightforward answer with bazel. However, with serverless framework, packaging is made very easy with the pip / pipfile extension. Also, with SAM framework (made by AWS) this is very simple as well.

Comment: Also, you are on the right way. You need to have 1/ a python file that has an handler function that accepts two and only two arguments 2/ all the libraries packaged at the root of your zip.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The thing with Bazel is that the requirements.txt is at the workspace (i.e. repo) level and it includes the dependencies for all lambdas vs. individual lambdas. So although I could use the workspace requirements.txt to generate the zip, the resulting zip will have more dependencies than what are actually needed. I was hoping that Bazel will have a "simple" way to generate a zip file containing the source code and dependencies for a single Bazel target (i.e. lambda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the changes I made to the previous answer to generate the lambda zip. Thanks @jvolkman for the original suggestion.

***project/BUILD.bazel:*** Added rule to generate `requirements_lock.txt` from `project/requirements.txt`

```
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "compile_pip_requirements")

compile_pip_requirements(
    name = "requirements",
    extra_args = ["--allow-unsafe"],
    requirements_in = "requirements.txt",
    requirements_txt = "requirements_lock.txt",
)
```

***project/WORKSPACE.bazel***: swap pip_install with pip_parse

```
workspace(name = "mdc-eligibility")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    sha256 = "9fcf91dbcc31fde6d1edb15f117246d912c33c36f44cf681976bd886538deba6",
    strip_prefix = "rules_python-0.8.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/archive/refs/tags/0.8.0.tar.gz",
)

load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "python_register_toolchains")
python_register_toolchains(
    name = "python3_9",
    python_version = "3.9",
)

load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_parse")
load("@python3_9//:defs.bzl", "interpreter")
pip_parse(
   name = "mndc-eligibility-deps",
   requirements_lock = "//:requirements_lock.txt",
   python_interpreter_target = interpreter,
   quiet = False
)
load("@mndc-eligibility-deps//:requirements.bzl", "install_deps")
install_deps()
```

***project/build_rules/lambda_packaging/lambda.bzl:*** Modified custom rule provided by @jvolkman to include source code in the resulting zip code.

```
def contains(pattern):
    return "contains:" + pattern

def startswith(pattern):
    return "startswith:" + pattern

def endswith(pattern):
    return "endswith:" + pattern

def _is_ignored(path, patterns):
    for p in patterns:
        if p.startswith("contains:"):
            if p[len("contains:"):] in path:
                return True
        elif p.startswith("startswith:"):
            if path.startswith(p[len("startswith:"):]):
                return True
        elif p.startswith("endswith:"):
            if path.endswith(p[len("endswith:"):]):
                return True
        else:
            fail("Invalid pattern: " + p)

    return False

def _short_path(file_):
    # Remove prefixes for external and generated files.
    # E.g.,
    #   ../py_deps_pypi__pydantic/pydantic/__init__.py -> pydantic/__init__.py
    short_path = file_.short_path
    if short_path.startswith("../"):
        second_slash = short_path.index("/", 3)
        short_path = short_path[second_slash + 1:]
    return short_path

# steven chambers

def _py_lambda_zip_impl(ctx):
    deps = ctx.attr.target[DefaultInfo].default_runfiles.files

    f = ctx.outputs.output

    args = []
    for dep in deps.to_list():
        short_path = _short_path(dep)

        # Skip ignored patterns
        if _is_ignored(short_path, ctx.attr.ignore):
            continue

        args.append(short_path + "=" + dep.path)

    # MODIFICATION: Added source files to the map of files to zip
    source_files = ctx.attr.target[DefaultInfo].files
    for source_file in source_files.to_list():
        args.append(source_file.basename+"="+source_file.path)

    ctx.actions.run(
        outputs = [f],
        inputs = deps,
        executable = ctx.executable._zipper,
        arguments = ["cC", f.path] + args,
        progress_message = "Creating archive...",
        mnemonic = "archiver",
    )

    out = depset(direct = [f])
    return [
        DefaultInfo(
            files = out,
        ),
        OutputGroupInfo(
            all_files = out,
        ),
    ]

_py_lambda_zip = rule(
    implementation = _py_lambda_zip_impl,
    attrs = {
        "target": attr.label(),
        "ignore": attr.string_list(),
        "_zipper": attr.label(
            default = Label("@bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper"),
            cfg = "host",
            executable = True,
        ),
        "output": attr.output(),
    },
    executable = False,
    test = False,
)

def py_lambda_zip(name, target, ignore, **kwargs):
    _py_lambda_zip(
        name = name,
        target = target,
        ignore = ignore,
        output = name + ".zip",
        **kwargs
    )
```

***project/appcode/api/transaction_details/src/BUILD.bazel***: Used custom `py_lambda_zip` rule to zip up `py_library`

```
load("@mndc-eligibility-deps//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")
load("@python3_9//:defs.bzl", "interpreter")
load("//build_rules/lambda_packaging:lambda.bzl", "contains", "endswith", "py_lambda_zip", "startswith")

py_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = glob(["*.py"]),
    visibility = ["//appcode/api/transaction_details:__subpackages__"],
    deps = [
            requirement("Faker"),
        ],
)

py_lambda_zip(
    name = "lambda_archive",
    ignore = [
        contains("/__pycache__/"),
        endswith(".pyc"),
        endswith(".pyo"),

        # Ignore boto since it's provided by Lambda.
        startswith("boto3/"),
        startswith("botocore/"),

        # With the move to hermetic toolchains, the zip gets a lib/ directory containing the
        # python runtime. We don't need that.
        startswith("lib/"),
    ],
    target = ":main",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

We use `@bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper` with a custom rule. We also pull `serverless` in using `rules_nodejs` and run it through bazel, which causes the package building to happen prior to running `sls deploy`.

We use `pip_parse` from `rules_python`. I'm not sure whether the `_short_path` function below will work with `pip_install` or other mechanisms.

File filtering is supported, although it's awkward. Ideally the zip generation would be handled by a separate binary (i.e., a Python script) which would allow filtering using regular expressions/globs/etc. Bazel doesn't support regular expressions in Starlark, so we use our own thing.

I've included an excerpt:

`lambda.bzl`

```
"""
Support for serverless deployments.
"""

def contains(pattern):
    return "contains:" + pattern

def startswith(pattern):
    return "startswith:" + pattern

def endswith(pattern):
    return "endswith:" + pattern

def _is_ignored(path, patterns):
    for p in patterns:
        if p.startswith("contains:"):
            if p[len("contains:"):] in path:
                return True
        elif p.startswith("startswith:"):
            if path.startswith(p[len("startswith:"):]):
                return True
        elif p.startswith("endswith:"):
            if path.endswith(p[len("endswith:"):]):
                return True
        else:
            fail("Invalid pattern: " + p)

    return False

def _short_path(file_):
    # Remove prefixes for external and generated files.
    # E.g.,
    #   ../py_deps_pypi__pydantic/pydantic/__init__.py -> pydantic/__init__.py
    short_path = file_.short_path
    if short_path.startswith("../"):
        second_slash = short_path.index("/", 3)
        short_path = short_path[second_slash + 1:]
    return short_path

def _py_lambda_zip_impl(ctx):
    deps = ctx.attr.target[DefaultInfo].default_runfiles.files

    f = ctx.outputs.output

    args = []
    for dep in deps.to_list():
        short_path = _short_path(dep)

        # Skip ignored patterns
        if _is_ignored(short_path, ctx.attr.ignore):
            continue

        args.append(short_path + "=" + dep.path)

    ctx.actions.run(
        outputs = [f],
        inputs = deps,
        executable = ctx.executable._zipper,
        arguments = ["cC", f.path] + args,
        progress_message = "Creating archive...",
        mnemonic = "archiver",
    )

    out = depset(direct = [f])
    return [
        DefaultInfo(
            files = out,
        ),
        OutputGroupInfo(
            all_files = out,
        ),
    ]

_py_lambda_zip = rule(
    implementation = _py_lambda_zip_impl,
    attrs = {
        "target": attr.label(),
        "ignore": attr.string_list(),
        "_zipper": attr.label(
            default = Label("@bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper"),
            cfg = "host",
            executable = True,
        ),
        "output": attr.output(),
    },
    executable = False,
    test = False,
)

def py_lambda_zip(name, target, ignore, **kwargs):
    _py_lambda_zip(
        name = name,
        target = target,
        ignore = ignore,
        output = name + ".zip",
        **kwargs
    )
```

`BUILD.bazel`

```
load("@npm_serverless//serverless:index.bzl", "serverless")
load(":lambda.bzl", "contains", "endswith", "py_lambda_zip", "startswith")

py_binary(
    name = "my_lambda_app",
    ...
)

py_lambda_zip(
    name = "lambda_archive",
    ignore = [
        contains("/__pycache__/"),
        endswith(".pyc"),
        endswith(".pyo"),
        
        # Ignore boto since it's provided by Lambda.
        startswith("boto3/"),
        startswith("botocore/"),

        # With the move to hermetic toolchains, the zip gets a lib/ directory containing the
        # python runtime. We don't need that.
        startswith("lib/"),
    ],
    target = ":my_lambda_app",

    # Only allow building on linux, since we don't want to upload a lambda zip file
    # with e.g. macos compiled binaries.
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
    ],
)

# The sls command requires that serverless.yml be in its working directory, and that the yaml file
# NOT be a symlink. So this target builds a directory containing a copy of serverless.yml, and also 
# symlinks the generated lambda_archive.zip in the same directory.
#
# It also generates a chdir.js script that we instruct node to execute to change to the proper working directory.
genrule(
    name = "sls_files",
    srcs = [
        "lambda_archive.zip",
        "serverless.yml",
    ],
    outs = [
        "sls_files/lambda_archive.zip",
        "sls_files/serverless.yml",
        "sls_files/chdir.js",
    ],
    cmd = """
        mkdir -p $(@D)/sls_files
        cp $(location serverless.yml) $(@D)/sls_files/serverless.yml
        cp -P $(location lambda_archive.zip) $(@D)/sls_files/lambda_archive.zip

        echo "const fs = require('fs');" \
             "const path = require('path');" \
             "process.chdir(path.dirname(fs.realpathSync(__filename)));" > $(@D)/sls_files/chdir.js
    """,
)

# Usage:
#   bazel run //:sls -- deploy <more args>
serverless(
    name = "sls",
    args = ["""--node_options=--require=./$(location sls_files/chdir.js)"""],
    data = [
        "sls_files/chdir.js",
        "sls_files/serverless.yml",
        "sls_files/lambda_archive.zip",
    ],
)
```

`serverless.yml`

```
service: my-app

package:
  artifact: lambda_archive.zip

# ... other config ...
```

Comment: Wondering at which point the flat zip file with the src code and runtime dependencies is generated? The zip that gets generated from the `py_lambda_zip` rule contains the following direcotries: appcode (src directory), bin, include, pypi__faker, pypi__python_dateutil, pypi__six, pypi__six

Comment: I believe the `pypi__` prefixes mean you're using `pip_install`, not `pip_parse` (see the `rules_python` docs). If you switch to the latter it should work better. Otherwise you'll need to tweak the script that builds zip files to strip out the `pypi__` prefixes. The zip file should contain `faker`, `python_dateutil`, `six`, etc. directories.